# wpf responsive ListBox / Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I am trying to recreate the following responsive grid (see 'Desired behavior' link below) in WPF. But, I am struggling to find the best way to achieve this.

Ideally, I would like a horizontal list of tiles that grow and shrink in size to fit the available space. As a starting point, I have a list box that wraps, but i'm left with white space when re-sizing.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Current Wrap Panel: 
[image: Current Wrap Panel] :

[Desired behavior](http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/)

My current Code:

```
<Window x:Class="WrappingListbox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="Wrapping Listbox"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>

    <ListBox x:Name="listbox1" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Viewbox>
                        <Grid x:Name="backgroundGrid"
                              Width="60"
                              Height="60">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="Rect" Fill="green" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Viewbox>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>


    <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />


</Grid>
```

Comment: You've hard coded the grid's width and height they won't grow or shrink to fill the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will solve the size problem for you (by binding the dimensions of the item to the dimensions of the listbox but I think you need to work more on it but here is just the start )

```
// add this in your window definition 
xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
//then here is your listbox 
<ListBox x:Name="listbox1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <Local:DimentionConverter x:Key="Converter" />
            </ListBox.Resources>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                        <Viewbox>
                            <Grid x:Name="backgroundGrid"
                             Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox},Path=ActualWidth,Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=Converter},ConverterParameter=5}"
                             Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox},Path=ActualWidth,Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=Converter},ConverterParameter=5}" >
                                <Rectangle x:Name="Rect" Fill="green" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

public class DimentionConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (double)value / double.Parse(parameter as string);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Important Notice :** you can't do it without the converter you have to use it to decide how big you want your item compared to the hosting listbox ofcourse you can change the value as you wish I made it 5 as an example